# urllib2 throws UnicodeEncodeError on image URL

Tags: python, urllib2

My application needs to fetch image urls, check that they are actually pointing to an image, and then do some more things. Bellow is my method that checks that a URL is valid.

```
 @staticmethod
  def urlReturnsOK(url):
    """ Check that the given URL links to an existing image, return false if not """

    try:
      response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
      if response.code == 200:
        return True
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
      logging.debug('Testing URL: %s returned HTTPError %s' % (url, e.code))
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
      logging.debug('Testing URL: %s returned URLError %s' % (url, e.args))
    except UnicodeEncodeError, e:
      logging.debug("THIS CAUSES PROBLEMS +++++++++ %s "% url)

    return False
```

On some of the URLs(all are pointing to images, assuming they are correct) I am getting the following exception:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in
>   position 49: ordinal not in range(128)

When adding an expect clause, I can see that one URL that causes trouble is this(notice the non standard letters):

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/BustAntonioGutiérrezdeOteroySantayana.PNG/200px-BustAntonioGutiérrezdeOteroySantayana.PNG

Next in an attempt to debug I do the following in python script:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/BustAntonioGutiérrezdeOteroySantayana.PNG/200px-BustAntonioGutiérrezdeOteroySantayana.PNG')
>>> print response.code
200
>>>
```

At this point I am not sure what I need to change, and cant explain why the method works on console, but not in my code. I am assuming that the problem lies on the non-standard letters, but dont know how to fix it. Any suggestions ?

**UPDATE**

As it was suggested, this question was already answered, although I still do not understand why opening the link from console worked ?

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Is that coming from your actual Unicode except clause, or somewhere else? I suspect the latter.

Comment: With the UnicodeEncodeError I dont get exception. That exception is thrown when I dont have the expect clause

Comment: @Giannis You must still be getting the exception and its traceback printed on the console (or wherever your `stderr` points). In any case, do write the full (related) output of your script.